# Integrating $ 3 \int \frac{\cos^5 x}{\sin x} dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to solve the integral $$3 \int  \frac{\cos^5 x}{\sin x} dx$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I think Integration by Parts may be useful, but I'm not entirely sure what to make $u$ and $dv$.

Comment: Maybe writing $\frac{\cos^5 x}{\sin x} = \frac{(1 - \sin^2 x)^2}{\sin x}\cos x$ and calling $u = \sin x$?

Answer (score 4):

**A start:** Note that $\cos^4x=(1-\sin^2 x)^2$. Let $u=\sin x$.

Comment: I haven't worked it out yet, but I see that this will work. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it is downhill from now on, expand the $(1-u^2)^2$, divide term by term by $u$, and integrate term by term.

Answer (score 3):

with $t=\cos(x)$ we get
$dt=-\sin(x)dx$ and we obtain
$-3 \int \frac{t^5}{\sin(x)^2}dt=-3\int \frac{t^5}{1-t^2}dt$
Sonnhard.

Comment: Is the second integral supposed to be easily solvable?

Comment: The next step would be polynomial long division.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

To integrate such trigonometric fractions , you have to look at the degrees. If the integrand is of the form $\sin x\,F(\cos x)/G(\cos x)$ or $\cos x\,F(\sin x)/G(\sin x)$, the change of variable to an ordinary rational fraction is easy.

The cases of $\sin x\,F(\cos x,\sin^2x)/G(\cos x,\sin^2x)$ and $\cos x\,F(\sin x,\cos^2x)/G(\sin x,\cos^2x)$ are handled similary by using the identity $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Answer (score -1):

$$
\int \frac{\cos^5x}{\sin x}\,dx
=
\int\frac{\cos^4x \cdot \cos x}{\sin x}\,dx
$$
$$
=
\int \frac{(1-\sin^2 x)^2  \cos x}{\sin x}\, dx
$$
Then put $t=\sin x$ then $dt=\cos x\, dx$

Then the integral is equal to
$$\int\frac{(1-t^2)^2}{t}\, dt$$

Comment: @Leucippus: unless the answer was completed in the meantime, I don't see a problem with this answer. The final steps are self-evident.